# TensorFlow C++ what does "NOLINT(build/namespaces)" mean?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Odd question here, at various places in the C++ code portions of TensorFlow on Github there is the following comment:

```
// NOLINT(build/namespaces)
```

For example, the C++ label image example has this comment:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc#L120

```
Status ReadTensorFromImageFile(const string& file_name, const int input_height,
                               const int input_width, const float input_mean,
                               const float input_std,
                               std::vector<Tensor>* out_tensors) {
  auto root = tensorflow::Scope::NewRootScope();
  using namespace ::tensorflow::ops;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)

  string input_name = "file_reader";
  string output_name = "normalized";
  .
  .
  .
```

Can anybody explain what `// NOLINT(build/namespaces)` means ?? I would try to research it more myself but I'm not even sure where to begin.

Comment: Looks like a comment that some lint tool will pick up on and use to suppress some warning message.

Comment: Just search for "C++" and "NOLINT" and browse a few of the results that come up.

Comment: From the name of the suppression "build/namespaces" it looks more like a suppression for the `cpplint` linter in particular (which mostly follows Google rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linters are tools to check the code for style and correctness in a static way. One of those tools used by TensorFlow developers and other is [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/).

While those tools are very useful to spot mistakes, sometimes the general checks don't apply (for instance in generated code, highly optimized code or when purposely using outdated APIs for backwards compatibility) in such cases an annotation like `//NOLINT` can be used to tell the linter not to report errors,to keep false-positives low and the results  meaningful.

Each of these places should state a reason, so developers know what is being ignored and why, an should regularly be reviewed, so changes due to updates are detected.

See also the section on suppression: http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#suppressing-undesired-diagnostics